# expected primary-expression before '*' token problem

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to write information to a file but the function that writes the information to the file keeps giving me:

> expected primary-expression before '*' token.

I've tried changing the syntax and modifying some of the other parts of my code but whenever I do that I just get more errors

This the beginning of the code

```
#define THEFILE "File.dat"
using namespace std; 
int main(void)
{
char a[6]; // allocate static buffer
int Data[5] = {2,3,4,5,6};
FILE *file;
file = fopen( THEFILE ,"w" );
fwrite(*Data,6,6,FILE *file);
```

this is the part that is giving me errors

```
fwrite(*Data,6,6,FILE *file);
```

The Fwrite should be writing 2,3,4,5,6 to the new pointer file created

Comment: `fwrite(Data, sizeof(Data), 1, file);`

Comment: For a start: remove the `FILE` :: `fwrite(Data,6,6,file);` (and,  of course, you dont need the`*` before `Data`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks more C++ than C.

```
using namespace std;

#define THEFILE "File.dat"

int main(void)
{
    int Data[5] = {2,3,4,5,6};
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(THEFILE, "w");
    fwrite(Data, sizeof(Data[0]), sizeof(Data) / sizeof(Data[0]), file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I use like a mix of c and c++ sorry, I should had made that clear and also thanks for your help!